# snakemake rule without an output directive

Tags: python, snakemake

let's assume I have a snakemake rule like this:

```
rule test:
  input: myfile="myfile.txt",
  params: test_out = "test",
  shell:  "tool {input.myfile} -p ~/desktop/{params.test_out}
```

The tool does not support an -o option to specify the output, but provides -p to specify the prefix of the file.

Basically the tool takes some input, processes the files and generates multiple output files. But if I have a rule all at the top of my script, it won't execute this rule since it does not include an output directive. How can I still generate an output for this rule along with the output of the other rules specified in rule all?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have an output, and if you know it you should tell snakemake.  As an example, let's say you knew `output.txt` was going to be the output:

```
rule test:
  input: myfile="myfile.txt",
  output: "test/output.txt"
  params: test_out = lambda wildcards, output: Path(output[0].parent),
  shell:  "tool {input.myfile} -p {params.test_out}
```

You know the output file, you just need to translate that to the expected parameter.  Some considerations here are if the tool always outputs to `output.txt` regardless of input you have to have unique subdirectories per sample to prevent clobbering.

It may also be that the tool produces an indeterminate number of files, e.g. `output_{1..n}.txt` but you can specify the directory.  Then you'd have

```
rule test:
  input: myfile="myfile.txt",
  output: directory("test")
  shell:  "mkdir -p {output} ; tool {input.myfile} -p {output}
```

With `directory` outputs, snakemake no longer auto creates parent directories so you have to do that manually.  Any rules which consume tool outputs may also need the rule to be a `checkpoint` so the outputs can be queried before execution.